# Azure Log Analytics Custom Log with multiple file paths. How can I tell which file the records in Log Analytics came from?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am working on a client that has Custom Logs setup in Azure Log Analytics. Some of the Custom Logs have many individual file paths added. When I query the Custom Log in Log Analytics is there a way to tell which actual file generated the data I am looking at? All the data is in the 'RawData' column but I cannot determine which file path triggered the data in 'RawData'. I would prefer not to have to create separate Custom Logs for each individual file path if I can avoid!
Thanks
C

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't have a way to tell which actual file generated the data in this case. I see [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-monitor-log-analytics/suggestions/34587253-custom-logs-should-include-a-file-name-or-path) feature request already created for the same in uservoice / feedback forum and has 57 votes as on date.

Currently it's under review and there is no ETA yet on this one.

I would recommend you to upvote the feature request. In general Azure feature / product team would check feasibility of a feature request, prioritize against existing feature backlog, add them in roadmap as appropriate and would announce and/or update the related Azure document once a feature request is addressed.